# Balak ending on a sad note

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, torah-service, parashat-balak

The end of parshas Balak is the sin at Shitim with the Bnos Moav, culminating in the sin of Zimri and Cozbi. Pinchas kills them both, stopping the plague. That would have been a good place to stop, but the last verse says (Numbers 25:9):

> וַיִּהְי֕וּ הַמֵּתִ֖ים בַּמַּגֵּפָ֑ה אַרְבָּעָ֥ה וְעֶשְׂרִ֖ים אָֽלֶף׃
>
> Those who died of the plague numbered twenty-four thousand.

That's a rather depressing note. The Rema in OC 138:1 says:

> . וִיכַוֵּן שֶׁיַּתְחִיל תָּמִיד לִקְרֹא בְּדָבָר טוֹב, וִיסַיֵּם בְּדָבָר טוֹב
>
> And one should aim to always begin to read on a good matter and to end on a good matter

Why does the parsha end in a way that doesn't fit this halacha? Better yet, stop before the whole story with Shittim. I must admit I haven't checked this Rema against every aliyah in the Torah, and for all I know there are other counter examples, but this one is pretty striking. Now I wonder if someone would argue that it's good the sinners died, but I think it's pretty bad that the sinning got to such a level that that many died.

Comment: Better yet, why not end the parshah later on, when HaShem rewards Pinchas for his actions?

Comment: Where to end the parsha isn't a choice, as Aliyah breaks are. That halakha is about Aliyah breaks within a parsha

Comment: Noach ends with Terach's death. Toldos ends with Eisav joining forces with Yishmael to kill Yaakov at the right opportunity. Mikeitz ends with the winebearer forgetting Yosef. Vayechi ends with Yosef's death. Va'eira ends with Paroh reneging on his promise to let the Jews go. Ki Seitzei ends with the pleasant reminder of what Amalek did and the commandment to wipe them out. Ha'azinu ends with HaShem telling Moshe he won't enter Eretz Yisrael. Vezos Haberachah ends with Moshe's death, and that nobody will ever be like he was. (Con't)

Comment: For those communities that read Im Kesef, the parshah ends with the curse that one who afflicts orphans and widows, his wife will become a widow and his children orphans, and he will die.

Comment: As @DoubleAA alluded to, the siman you quoted, with its discussion of reading no less than 3 Pesukim rather than 10 would seem to be discussing aliyos rather than parshios.

Comment: @Double-AA good point, so I guess this question is unjustified then?

Comment: @robev Perhaps you could ask why the parshios were broken up that way so that their final Aliyah is in violation of this Halacha, though I'm not sure there is a basis to ask that question.

Comment: Btw, to add to my list above, Vayigash ends with Yosef's threat to keep Binyamin as a slave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Baruch Hashem*, I'm not alone. This question is addressed by various sources, all brought in **Ma Shehaya Hu Sheyihyeh** *Shir HaShirim* II 5:3 fn. 8 by **Rabbi Eliyahu Wolf** from Yeshivas Ner Yisroel, Baltimore. He brings as follows:

**Birkas Aharon** *Berachos* § 268 by [**Rav Aharon Levine**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9F) asks this question, as well on [how *parshas Kedoshim* ends](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). He leaves it as צ"ע.

## Death of the Erev Rav

**Pardes Yosef HeChadash** *Balak* § 212 (at the end) suggests an answer:

> י"ל ע"פ מש"כ בזוה"ק פ' פנחס דהכ"ד אלף שמתו במגפה היו מערב רב שהולידו מבנות שבט שמעון

He brings from the **Zohar** III [p. 236b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.236b.8?vhe=Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi) that the 24,000 people who died in the plague were really the wicked *erev rav*. The reason the verse says they're from the tribe of Shimon is because these were offspring from the *erev rav* who married woman from the tribe of Shimon.

Presumably it's good that the *erev rav* died, as they were a negative influence. Even though these individuals were raised by Jewish mothers, it sounds like the **Pardes Yosef HeChadash** is suggesting that they too were wicked (presumably because of their wicked fathers, and the fact that their mothers married them proves they weren't too good either).

**Chomas Anach** [*Balak* § 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Chomat_Anakh_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.25.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) by the **Chida** also brings the **Zohar**. Not clear if he's addressing this question also, or just wants you to know about the **Zohar**.

Also, [Sanhedrin 106a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.106a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says ‏כ"ד אלף [שהפיל מישראל]‏, with the last words in brackets. [**Margaliyos HaYam**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuvein_Margolies) *Sanhedrin* 106a § 14 points out that this could work with the opinion of the **Zohar**, that these words don't belong here.

## Doesn't apply

In **Ma Shehaya Hu Sheyihyeh** *Haftaros* I p. 87 fn. 5, he brings a few other sources.

The [**Maharsham**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholom_Mordechai_Schwadron) (in his glosses to **Moed Katan** 28b) asks this question. His first answer doesn't seem to be helpful here, as he is addressing *parshas Kedoshim* and says that verse is talking to *Beis Din*. His second answer sounds like he's saying that the entire Torah is good. As well, it's all letters from the name of Hashem. It sounds like according to this, he's saying this halacha doesn't apply

The **Ben Ish Chai** in **Rav Pe'alim** IV *Orach Chaim* [§ 42](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1402&pgnum=55) answers that this rule only applied when there was the original *halacha* that only the first person makes a *beracha* on reading the Torah and the last person (**Megillah** 21a). The people in between shouldn't finish their *aliya* on a negative note. However, the person who makes the *beracha*, that is really how they're "ending". That's always considered ending on a positive note. Today, where everyone makes a *beracha* after, it always ends on a positive note. This *halacha* doesn't apply then.

According to these answers, I'm not sure why the **Rema** brought this *halacha*.